# Unity C# Convert float to byte array and read with node js

Tags: c#, node.js, floating-point, buffer, arrays

Can someone explain how I can convert a float(Vector3.x) to a byte array with c# and decode it with node js?

I read on the internet that Vector3.x is a system.single data type and use 4 bytes(32 bits). I use BitConverter to convert it to a byte array. With Nodejs I use readFloatBE().

I don`t know what I'm doing wrong, but I get constantly a bad result with node js with console.log().

Unity csharp:

```
     public static int FloatToBit(int offset, ref byte[] data, Single number)
     {
         byte[] byteArray = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
        for (int i = 0;i<4;i++)
         {
             data[offset + i] = byteArray[i];
         }

         return 4;
     }
```

Node js

```
     readFloat: function (offset, data) {
        var b = new Buffer(4);
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {       
               b[i] = data[offset + i];
           }     
        return data.readFloatLE(b, 0);
     },
```

If I send -2.5, unity output is: 0 0 32 191 with -1 unity output is: 0 0 128 192

Nodejs output with readFloatLE: 3.60133705331478e-43

Comment: Documentation shows- `const buf = Buffer.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
buf.readDoubleBE();
  // Returns: 8.20788039913184e-304
buf.readDoubleLE();
  // Returns: 5.447603722011605e-270`. But I don't know why. Curious myself.

Comment: Careful with `new Buffer(size)`. That is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_size) with the most recent version of node. It might *technically* be okay, since you're overwriting the 4 bytes anyways, but I wanted to bring it up.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson side note: those are just the numbers represented. What you're making is a buffer containing `0x0102030405060708`, and the doubles those represent are what you're seeing in your returns, based on whether you read them as big or little endian.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working set of data from front to back.

C#:

```
Single fl = 2.5F;
var bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(fl);
var str = BitConverter.ToString(bytes); // 00-00-20-40
```

Nodejs:

```
let buffer = Buffer.from([ 0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x40 ]);
let float = buffer.readFloatLE(); // 2.5
```

Note the method I used to create the buffer in nodejs, especially (also tested and verified with -1, but I left the code off for brevity).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

I put the same question over here:[Unity Questions](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1196961/convert-float-to-byte-array-and-read-with-node-js.html)

Somebody give me the answer to use:

```
  readFloat: function (offset, data) {
        return data.readFloatLE(offset);
```

},

instead creating a new buffer.

Parameter is a buffer. This was working for me. I still don`t understand why my example is not working.